# Droppar as tabelas do meu schema no Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqldeveloper

Estou utilizando um Schema no Oracle (sql developer) e dentro do meu esquema já existem várias tabelas criadas que estava utilizando anteriormente. 
Agora rodando um script novo nesse esquema ele apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
Relatório de erros -
ORA-00955: nome já está sendo usado por um objeto existente
00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Eu sei que o motivo do erro é que já existe um tabela com o mesmo nome no schema, porém minha dúvida é...
No Postgres eu utilizava `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS name_table CASCADE;` e no oracle não é permitido utilizar desta maneira, existe algum comando similar que tenha o mesmo propósito? Que toda vez que eu recompile (F5) o script inteiro ele substitua as tabelas?

Comment: https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/561832-cria%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-banco-com-if-else/?do=findComment&comment=2240883  veja se ajuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para solucionar este problema você necessitará abrir um bloco anonimo de sql, conferir antes se existe e caso não exista criar:

**Criar se não existir**

```
declare
nCount NUMBER;
v_sql LONG;

begin
SELECT count(*) into nCount FROM dba_tables where table_name = 'EMPLOYEE';
IF(nCount <= 0)
THEN
v_sql:='
create table EMPLOYEE
(
ID NUMBER(3),
NAME VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL
)';
execute immediate v_sql;

END IF;
end;
```

**Dropar Caso exista**

```
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE mytable';
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
         RAISE;
      END IF;
END;
```